# spacyr initialisation in R is not recognising Spacy module

Tags: python, r, pip, spacy

`spacy_initialize(model = "en_core_web_sm")`

This line is producing the error:

Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) :
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'

This is despite

spacy              3.5.0
spacy-alignments   0.9.0
spacy-legacy       3.0.12
spacy-loggers      1.0.4
spacy-transformers 1.2.2

appearing in my `pip list` using Windows Powershell: my version of python is a new installation of 3.11 after deleting the previous python installations on my computer.

Why is R refusing to recognise Spacy in initialisation?

tl;dr I was expecting `spacy_initialize(model = "en_core_web_sm")` to allow use of spacyr in R. I know spacy is installed on my computer as it is in the pip list. I have reinstalled spacy as a module to make sure there wasn't an issue there.

Comment: Its not clear to me how you call python from R, does it currently work with other modules you installed through pip?

Comment: spacyr is an R package that allows spacy to be called in R despite being a python module. Thus, it utilises python in order to do this. It's similar to how Stargazer does not use R code to function despite being an R package.

Comment: I mean what python version is in your .Rprofile , this is what i mean how you call python from R